# Save draft to specific 'Drafts' subfolder

Tags: vba, outlook

I know how to compose a message in Outlook VBA, and save it as a draft.     In most cases, a user has only a single 'folder', so the default location of the draft is fine.
However, if the user has multiple folders, each folder can have it's own 'Drafts' subfolder.

When saving a draft, how can I specify WHICH DRAFTS folder it is saved to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, all new items are saved to the Drafts folder when created manually.  You need to use the `Move` method if an Outlook item is saved to the folder.

If you create items programmatically you need to use the `Items.Add` method to get it saved to the right folder automatically. Read more about possible ways of  creating new items in Outlook in the [How to create and show a new Outlook mail item programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/26/outlook-create-show-message-programmatically/) article.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Eugene.         I have succeeded in creating the message in drafts, and then moving it where I want it to go.